# XSLT Convert XML Elements to HTML Table with different row count

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I used template matching to extract my elements and render them as an HTML table. However I'm having problems with my current output as the Children count are not equal.

In the below XML, the 2nd Parent has more Children that the 1st. If I convert it to HTML table, how do I make Row 4 Column 1 to show blank?

I intend to put all the elements in `<cells>` first, then from there I will convert it to Table using Muenchian grouping (separate code from the XSLT below).

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Table>
  <Parent>
    <Head>Header 1</Head>
    <Children>
      <Node>Node 1</Node>
      <Node>Node 2</Node>
      <Node>Node 3</Node>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Head>Header 2</Head>
    <Children>
      <Node>Node 4</Node>
      <Node>Node 5</Node>
      <Node>Node 6</Node>
      <Node>Node 7</Node>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</Table>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <cells>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent[1]" mode="parent">
                <xsl:with-param name="row" select="1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col" select="1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>  
        </cells>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent" mode="parent">
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:param name="col"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Children/Node[1]" mode="child">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="parent">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node" mode="child">
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:param name="col"/>

        <cell row="{$row}" col="{$col}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </cell>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="child">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output (cells):**

```
<cells>
   <cell row="1" col="1">Node 1</cell>
   <cell row="2" col="1">Node 2</cell>
   <cell row="3" col="1">Node 3</cell>
   <cell row="4" col="1"> </cell>
   <cell row="1" col="2">Node 4</cell>
   <cell row="2" col="2">Node 5</cell>
   <cell row="3" col="2">Node 6</cell>
   <cell row="4" col="2">Node 7</cell>
</cells>
```

**Expected HTML table:**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Node 1</td>
      <td>Node 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Node 2</td>
      <td>Node 5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Node 3</td>
      <td>Node 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Node 7</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see no Muenchian grouping in your XSLT. And your result is not an HTML table.-- P.S. Please post your code here, not in external links.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry for the confusion. I edited my post to update the expected output. I intend to generate a group of cells first, and from there I will create a table using Muenchian grouping.

Comment: But if that's your expected output, why not generate it directly?

Comment: I'm still studying how to convert it to <table> directly without the extra conversion to <cells> first

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you very much for your help! it looked cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by identifying the parent with the most children. Then, for each parent, create a cell for each child of the parent with the most children and populate it with value of the corresponding child of the current parent:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="parent-by-id" match="Parent" use="generate-id()" />

<xsl:template match="/Table">
    <!-- find the parent with most children -->
    <xsl:variable name="max-parent-id">
        <xsl:for-each select="Parent">
            <xsl:sort select="count(Children/Node)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
     <cells>
         <xsl:for-each select="Parent">
            <xsl:variable name="current-parent" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('parent-by-id', $max-parent-id)/Children/Node">
                <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />
                <cell row="{$j}" col="{$i}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$current-parent/Children/Node[$j]"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </cells>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

Given the expected HTML output in your edited question, you could change the order of operations to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Table">
    <xsl:variable name="all-parents" select="Parent" />
    <!-- find the parent with most children -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Parent">
        <xsl:sort select="count(Children/Node)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <!-- output -->
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="Children/Node">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$all-parents">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Children/Node[$i]" />
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

and get the expected output directly, with no need for an intermediate stage.

Comment: thank you! I merged this with my grouping code here: [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3A/1](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3A/1) to generate the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant code, but I'm able to render my HTML as expected. If you have any suggestions on how to make this code cleaner and more efficient, please let me know. Thanks!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <xsl:for-each select="Parent/Children">
             <xsl:sort select="count(Node)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
             <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <cells>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Parent[1]" mode="parent">
                        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="col" select="1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="count(Node)"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>  
                </cells>
             </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent" mode="parent">
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:param name="col"/>
        <xsl:param name="max-rows"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Children/Node[1]" mode="child">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="$max-rows"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="parent">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="$max-rows"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node" mode="child">
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:param name="col"/>
        <xsl:param name="max-rows"/>

        <cell row="{$row}" col="{$col}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </cell>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="child">
                    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="$max-rows"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:call-template name="Placeholder">
                    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="$max-rows"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name='Placeholder'>
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:param name="col"/>
        <xsl:param name="max-rows"/>

        <xsl:if test="$row &lt;= $max-rows">
            <cell row="{$row}" col="{$col}">
            </cell>
            <xsl:call-template name="Placeholder">
                <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="max-rows" select="$max-rows"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```