# split xml into tables and add ids

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to:

1. transform the nested xml into two tables/rectangles with xslt. (I've written the tables as csv, but It's fine if they're non-nested xml.)
2. arbitrary assign ids at both levels (eg, patient & tumor).
   (I've used letters so they stand out in this example, but sequential digits are probably preferable.)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NaaccrData baseDictionaryUri="http://naaccr.org/naaccrxml/naaccr-dictionary-230.xml" recordType="A" timeGenerated="2024-01-02T03:04:05.006-07:00"  specificationVersion="1.6">
    <Item naaccrId="recordType">A</Item>
    <Item naaccrId="registryType">01</Item>
    <Item naaccrId="registryId">02</Item>
    <Patient>
        <Item naaccrNum="1" naaccrId="p1">101</Item>
        <Item naaccrNum="2" naaccrId="p2">102</Item>
        <Item naaccrNum="3" naaccrId="p3">103</Item>
        <Tumor>
            <Item naaccrNum="11" naaccrId="t1">111</Item>
            <Item naaccrNum="12" naaccrId="t2">112</Item>
        </Tumor>
        <Tumor>
            <Item naaccrNum="11" naaccrId="t1">121</Item>
            <!-- notice 122 is missing -->
        </Tumor>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
        <Item naaccrNum="1" naaccrId="p1">201</Item>
        <Item naaccrNum="2" naaccrId="p2">202</Item>
        <Item naaccrNum="3" naaccrId="p3">203</Item>
        <Tumor>
            <Item naaccrNum="11" naaccrId="t1">211</Item>
            <Item naaccrNum="12" naaccrId="t2">212</Item>
        </Tumor>
    </Patient>
</NaaccrData>
```

Desired rectangle 1 & desired rectangle 2:

```
pt_id,p1,p2,p3
a,101,102,103
b,201,202,203

tumor_id,pt_id,t1,t2
x,a,111,112
y,a,121,
z,b,211,212
```

This xslt adequately handles the outer/patient level, but not the inner/tumor level.  It also doesn't assign ids.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/table">
        <Root><xsl:apply-templates /></Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Patient|Patient/Tumor">
        <pt>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item">
              <xsl:element name="{@naaccrId}"><xsl:value-of select = "."/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </pt>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using the [lxml](https://lxml.de/) Python package,
but I'm flexible on packages & languages.
The xml files are 100+MB.

```py
from lxml import etree

...

# load input
dom = etree.parse(path_raw)
print(dom)
# load XSLT
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse(path_xslt))
print(transform)

ds = transform(dom)
print(ds)
```

How do I produce those two desired rectangles?  Is xslt the best approach for this?  Am I asking too much of xslt?

**Edit**: In response to @y.arazim's comments below, here is some desired xml.  I'm flexible on this, because the ultimate goal is to upload two tables to a database.  I think this output would be good for that, but I'm new to this world and am open to suggestions.  Json would be fine with me too.

```xml
<pts>
  <pt>
    <p1>101</p1>
    <p2>102</p2>
    <p3>103</p3>
    <tumors>
      <tumor>
        <t1>111</t1>
        <t2>112</t2>
      </tumor>
      <tumor>
        <t1>121</t1>
        <!-- 122 is missing -->
      </tumor>
    </tumors>
  </pt>
  <pt>
    <p1>201</p1>
    <p2>202</p2>
    <p3>203</p3>
    <tumors>
      <tumor>
        <t1>211</t1>
        <t2>212</t2>
      </tumor>
    </tumors>
  </pt>
</pts>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the output XML format? It has no IDs and it **is** nested -contrary to what you said at the start.

Comment: yeah, I guess I got less ambitious throughout the day that it could be easily done in a single step.  Using some other posts, I think I can get it into rectangles now with some database functions, and hopefully I can add the IDs in that step.  I mostly didn't want to break it into rectangles and then have to infer IDs.  If you know how to do all this easily in one step, I'd love to learn from that .

Comment: How to produce all what? You are not showing us the final format you want.

Comment: BTW, here's a method you could combine with y.arazim's first suggestion to produce the CSV you originally wanted, even with some items missing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180439/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/NaaccrData">

    <!-- patients -->
    <xsl:text>pt_id,p1,p2,p3&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Patient">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    
    <!-- tumors -->
    <xsl:text>tumor_id,pt_id,t1,t2&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Patient">
        <xsl:variable name="pt_id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Tumor">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pt_id"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is an assumption here that each patient has the same number of items, and likewise for tumors.

---

**Added part:**

The XML output you added would be easy to produce using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/NaaccrData">
    <pts>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Patient"/>
    </pts>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="Patient">
    <pt>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
        <tumors>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Tumor"/>
        </tumors>
    </pt>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Tumor">
    <tumor>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
    </tumor>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:element name="{@naaccrId}">
        <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @y.arazim.  No.  Unfortunately some items are missing for some patients.  And most patients have just one tumor, but multiple tumors are possible according the [spec](https://www.naaccr.org/xml-user-dictionary/).

Comment: Then it will be complicated to produce a .csv with a common header. Could you edit your question and add the exact XML result you would want to have?

Comment: P.S The assumption is only about the number of items per patient and the number of items per tumor. Not about the number of tumors per patient. If that makes any difference.

Comment: thanks for these suggestions.  I've made edits that I hope clarify the goals.

Comment: @wibeasley I have added the code to produce the XML in the format you show.